# Swift: Unable to override operationDidFinish from GroupOperation class

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation

In a custom subclass of `GroupOperation`, I'm trying to override `operationDidFinish()`. When I attempt to implement the function in my subclass, I get this error message:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

If I remove the `override` keyword, I get

> Method 'operationDidFinish(*:withErrors:)' with Objective-C selector
>   'operationDidFinish:withErrors:' conflicts with method
>   'operationDidFinish(*:withErrors:)' from superclass 'GroupOperation'
>   with the same Objective-C selector

Weirdness. I'm pretty sure my method signature is spot on, and I'm not trying to overload an obj-c method, so all should be well. What gives?

For reference, my class looks like this:

```
class ServerAuthenticationOperation: GroupOperation {

     // properties... initializer stuff...

     override func operationDidFinish(operation: NSOperation, withErrors errors: [NSError]) {
          print("I finished!")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Swift 2.

Objective-C does not support method overloading, so you have to select a different name for your method. Or, you can try these options:

1. Rename the method using the `@objc(newMethodName:)`
2. Use `@nonobjc`

Edit:
It seems working for the repo you provided, you can check it here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hb07u3hyjhjuews/OverrideTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'm actually trying to override a function from a swift class. See the source for this class here: https://github.com/pluralsight/PSOperations/blob/master/PSOperations/GroupOperation.swift

Comment: Weird. I cloned the repo and added your method without any problems.

Comment: dang. I'll play around some more, must've done something else wrong. thanks for checking